# Writing a vector to a file in r

Tags: r, vector, export-to-csv

I want to write a vector to a csv file or text file. My data looks like this

```
> data
  x   y   z  xy 
100 101 102 103
```

I want the data to be written in the same format. I have gone through many posts but nothing works out. It would be of great help if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Could you share some code? If you e.g. save a vector with write.csv it would create several rows. So you might want to transpose your vector first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you are looking for sth. like this:

Data:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
names(x) <- LETTERS[1:4]
```

Saving:

```
x_for_saving <- t(x)
write.csv(x_for_saving, file = "my file.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I didn't know the transpose part. Thanks for the eye opener.

Comment: I'm able to write it to a csv file. But when I'm reading the csv back using read.csv it is getting read as a list.  Is there any way to read it as a dataframe?

Comment: I have no issues reading it bakc in as a data frame. As long as you don't provide a real example of your data along with specific code you were using, it's more or less impossibla at this point to further help you.